# getting long URL due to collection of complex objects passing in to GET method as a parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following form view ,

[image]

this is the [whole code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TflgTJ) for view page . here I have `FetchProductProperties` jsonresult to filter multiple properties in client side.

I have following `Create_Brochure` controller method to generate some html page in that page content divs generate if they checked in previous step

Once I do checked few ( 1 or 2 properties) then URL that getting with Create_Brochure method is shorter and working fine. but I checked multiple properties I'm getting wider URL and not working fine

[image]

Actually This is because I have a parameter which is a collection of complex objects in a GET method.

I want to hide `Property_Title` from this first view and then getting that values `Create_Brochure` view with solving this long URL problem.

Comment: Didn't I tell you not to do this in your last question :) Use a form to post the values

Comment: Instead of HttpGet action, change the action to HttpPost.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes you advised me this , then I use inside `form` tag

Comment: You need to do a POST, not a GET. But all your view contains is a few dropdowns and checkboxes, so that is all you should be submitting anyway (along with the ID's of the items associated with the checkboxes) - not the value of every property in your collection

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I use it with table , do I need to do like this https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqnbe

Comment: @kez, Not sure what your asking. So long as you have a form with `FormMethod.Post` then you can submit to a method marked with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this approach worked for me https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yqnbe then I'm getting clean URL like this `http://localhost:49669/Brochure/Create_Template` but have another function to generate PDFs , in that method since I'm referring post method its not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Direct your action in form to `FormMethod.Post`
2. add html elements for the form inside `<form> ... </form>` tags